# phpMyAdmin cookie key and temp dir errors in fresh installation

Tags: phpmyadmin

Running Alma Linux 9 with Apache.

Just performed `yum install phpMyAdmin`.

When I login mydomain.com/phpMyAdmin I get 2 warnings.

1. `The $cfg['TempDir'] (/var/lib/phpMyAdmin/temp/) is not accessible.`

   So `chmod 755 /var/lib/phpMyAdmin/temp` (was 750) fixed the issue.
   I don't know if this is the correct way to perform it.
2. `The configuration file needs a valid key for cookie encryption...`

   `/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php` has `$cfg['blowfish_secret']` already has a 32-bytes long key.

I don't know what to do here not to mess the things up.
I've read some similar threads but they don't apply the OS and phpMyAdmin version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues.
I fixed the `$cfg['blowfish_secret']` issue as follows:

1. In `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`, I only had a `config.sample.inc.php`, so I copied it to create `config.inc.php` into the same directory.
2. You will need a 32-bytes long string. You can get it from the terminal like this:

   ```
   php -r 'echo bin2hex(random_bytes(32)) . PHP_EOL;'
   ```
3. At the bottom of `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` I added:

   ```
   $cfg['blowfish_secret'] = sodium_hex2bin('32-bytes-long-string');
   $cfg['TempDir'] = 'tmp';
   $i=0;
   $i++;
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
   ```
4. Finally reload apache:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart apache2
   ```

Comment: Please use code formatting

Comment: I have used code formatting...something is wrong,...

Comment: Code in a list format needs to be indented *within* the list indentation, i.e. an additional 3 or 4 spaces - see my edit.